ajuda na autenticação de um webhook .net
estou desenvolvendo um webhook .NET que se comunica com a API de Cobrança da Sicredi, e para realizar requisições, preciso estar autenticado.
a API da Sicredi fornece um endpoints de autenticação, onde eu passo um username e um password e recebo access token, refresh token, tempos de expiração de cada um, etc.


{
  "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJBU0ZSSm1VMTBwaWRpbzFlQ254cXUzV2VwaDFjX2xJWFJDVXk5ZGpTZ0drIn0",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "refresh_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJmYzY3OWQwOS1lOTNhLTRlMzAtYmEzMi1iZWI2ZTQyZmNkMTQifQ",
  "expires_in": "3600",
  "refresh_expires_in": "900",
  "scope": "cobranca email profile"
}



não sei bem como utilizar o access token para autenticar as requisições, preciso de sugestões
fiz um método que acessa o endpoint de autenticação e retorna o access token, estava chamando esse método em cada uma das requisições e passando-o na header, mas sinto que não é a maneira correta.
MÉTODO DE OBTENÇÃO DE TOKEN


public async Task<AuthResponseModel> GetToken()
{
    //aqui, colocamos dentro da var client as características do cliente criado na classe program.cs
    var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("auth");

    //coloca dentro da var request uma instancia de FormUrlEncodedContent, que pra simplificar eh uma coleção de pares codificados na forma application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
    var request = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
    [
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "123456789"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "teste123"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "cobranca"),
    ]);

    //realizamos um post para o endpoint com a request (body informado acima)
    var response = await client.PostAsync("auth/openapi/token", request);

    //tratamentos!
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthResponseModel>(json);
    }
    else
    {
        var error = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        throw new Exception(error);
    }
}
//dados fixos apenas para testes



EXEMPLO DE REQUISIÇÃO


public async Task<CadastrarBoletoResponseModel> CadastrarBoleto(CadastrarBoletoRequestModel cadastrarBoletoRequest)
{
    //criação de cliente e obtenção de access token
    var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("cadastro");
    var token = await _authenticationInterface.GetToken();

    //adicionando o header Authorization
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.Access_token);

    if (cadastrarBoletoRequest.Pagador.Email != null)
    {
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(cadastrarBoletoRequest.Pagador.Email, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$"))
        {
            throw new Exception("email do pagador é invalido");
        }
    }
    
    if (cadastrarBoletoRequest.BeneficiarioFinal.Email != null)
    {
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(cadastrarBoletoRequest.BeneficiarioFinal.Email, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$"))
        {
            throw new Exception("email do beneficiario final é invalido");
        }
    }

    //na var request, adicionamos um objeto JSON com o nosso model serializado
    var request = JsonContent.Create(cadastrarBoletoRequest);

    //metodo post
    var response = await client.PostAsync("cobranca/boleto/v1/boletos", request);

    //tratamentos
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CadastrarBoletoResponseModel>(jsonResponse);
    }
    else
    {
        var error = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        throw new Exception(error);
    }
}




Evite ter a conta restrita ou bloqueada. Evite o flood, não duplique as publicações, siga as orientações passada na publicação original e lá faça as melhorias.

Não duplique perguntas, siga as instruções fornecidas na pergunta original. Os comentários aqui serão bloqueados para que continuem na pergunta original.
